# ¿Estoy aplicando bien mi EventHandler ActionEvent?

Tags: java, eventos

Hice mi primera una calculadora el cual utilice el EventHandler ActionEvent para darle eventos a mis botones, pero mi duda seria si aplique bien el eventHandler, me podrian dar su opinión profesional.
Aqui les dejo fragmentos del codigo

mis botones:

```
AnchorPane anchorPane = new AnchorPane();
TextField tf_Pantalla = new TextField("");  //Pantalla de resultados
TextField tf_SubPantalla = new TextField("");        //Pantalla de registro

Button btn_Clean = new Button("C");
Button btn_Delete = new Button("DEL");
Button btn_0 = new Button("0");
Button btn_1 = new Button("1");
Button btn_2 = new Button("2");
Button btn_3 = new Button("3");
Button btn_4 = new Button("4");
Button btn_5 = new Button("5");
Button btn_6 = new Button("6");
Button btn_7 = new Button("7");
Button btn_8 = new Button("8");
Button btn_9 = new Button("9");

Button btn_Punto = new Button(".");
Button btn_Suma = new Button("+");
Button btn_Resta = new Button("-");
Button btn_Multiplicacion = new Button("x");
Button btn_Division = new Button("/");
Button btn_Igual = new Button("=");
```

aqui relaciono cada boton con su metodo:

```
num0();
    num1();
    num2();
    num3();
    num4();
    num5();
    num6();
    num7();
    num8();
    num9();
    resta();
    suma();
    multiplicacion();
    division();
    borrar();
    eliminar();
    Resultado();
```

por ultimo aplico el evenHandler Acti.

```
private void num1 (){
    btn_1.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            tf_Pantalla.setText(tf_Pantalla.getText()+"1");
            tf_SubPantalla.setText(tf_SubPantalla.getText() + "1");
        }
    });
}


private void num2 (){
    btn_2.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            tf_Pantalla.setText(tf_Pantalla.getText()+"2");
            tf_SubPantalla.setText(tf_SubPantalla.getText() + "2");
        }
    });
}
```

los implemente en cada metodo de cada boton.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que buscas son consejos aqui te dejo algunos.

Podrías reducir el código para la creación de botones utilizando una lista y un for:

```java
List<Button> btns = new ArrayList<>();

for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
    btns.add( new Button(String.valueOf(x)) ); }
```

Para los manejadores de eventos podrias usar una [expresión lambda](https://www.adictosaltrabajo.com/2015/12/04/expresiones-lambda-con-java-8/):

```java
    btn_1.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {
    
        tf_Pantalla.setText(tf_Pantalla.getText()+"1");
        tf_SubPantalla.setText(tf_SubPantalla.getText() + "1");

    });
```

Incluso podrias reducir el codigo de los manejadores recorriendo la lista de botones con un `forEach`:

```java
    btns.forEach( (btn) -> {

        btn.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {
            
            tf_Pantalla.setText( tf_Pantalla.getText() + btn.getText() );
            tf_SubPantalla.setText( tf_SubPantalla.getText() + btn.getText() );

        });


    });
```

Para finalizar, podrias hacer todo lo referente a la creación y manejo de eventos de los botones de números con el siguiente código:

```java
List<Button> btns = new ArrayList<>();

Button tmpBtn = null;
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {

    tmpBtn = new Button( String.valueOf(x) );
    tmpBtn.setOnAction((actionEvent) -> {

        tf_Pantalla.setText( tf_Pantalla.getText() + tmpBtn.getText() );
        tf_SubPantalla.setText( tf_SubPantalla.getText() + tmpBtn.getText() );

    });

    btns.add(tmpBtn);

}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por los consejos.